# Add last hundread year list in input field dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add last hundreds years year list in dropdown list . How can I do that.

```js
var time = new Date();
var year = time.getYear();
if (year < 1900) {
    year = year + 1900;
}
var date = year - 101; /*change the '101' to the number of years in the past you want to show */
var future = year + 100; /*change the '100' to the number of years in the future you want to show */ 
document.writeln ("<FORM><SELECT><OPTION value=\"\">Year");
do {
    date++;
    document.write ("<OPTION value=\"" +date+"\">" +date+ "");
}
while (date < future)
document.write ("</SELECT></FORM>");
```

Comment: Do you want a PHP or JavaScript solution? You've tagged both - but only shown something from JavaScript.

Comment: What does PHP concern with this code?

Comment: @Qirel javascript

Comment: And why isn't what you have here working for you? What's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

date.getYear() is deprecated, use date.getFullYear() instead. 
an example:

```
<select id="selYears"></select>

var selectList = document.getElementById('selYears')
var d = new Date()
var year = d.getFullYear()
var past = 200 // change num here
var future = 250 // change num here
for(var i = (year - past);i <= (year + future); i++) {
       var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = i;
        option.text = i;
        selectList.appendChild(option);
}
```

**Edit**:

just change the for loop to decrement from maximum future date to lowest past date:

```
for(var i = (year + future);i >= (year - past); i--) {
           var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = i;
            option.text = i;
            selectList.appendChild(option);
}
```